# Ошибка при установке пакета composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer

из-за чего такая проблема при установке пакета?

```
composer-php7.3 require spatie/laravel-image-optimizer
Using version ^1.5 for spatie/laravel-image-optimizer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/framework (locked at v5.4.36, required as 5.7.*) is satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.36] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.2
    - spatie/laravel-image-optimizer 1.5.0 requires laravel/framework ~5.7.0|~5.8.0|^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.12, v5.7.13, v5.7.14, v5.7.15, v5.7.16, v5.7.17, v5.7.18, v5.7.19, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.24, v5.7.25, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.1
    - Installation request for spatie/laravel-image-optimizer ^1.5 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-image-optimizer[1.5.0].
    - Conclusion: remove swiftmailer/swiftmailer v5.4.12
    - Conclusion: don't install swiftmailer/swiftmailer v5.4.12
    - laravel/framework v5.7.0 requires swiftmailer/swiftmailer ^6.0 -> satisfiable by swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.1.0, v6.1.1, v6.1.2, v6.1.3, v6.2.0, v6.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.0.0, v5.4.12].
    - Can only install one of: swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.0.1, v5.4.12].
    - Can only install one of: swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.0.2, v5.4.12].
    - Can only install one of: swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.1.0, v5.4.12].
    - Can only install one of: swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.1.1, v5.4.12].
    - Can only install one of: swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.1.2, v5.4.12].
    - Can only install one of: swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.1.3, v5.4.12].
    - Can only install one of: swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.2.0, v5.4.12].
    - Can only install one of: swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.2.1, v5.4.12].
    - Installation request for swiftmailer/swiftmailer (locked at v5.4.12) -> satisfiable by swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v5.4.12].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас в composer.json версия laravel заблокирована на v5.4.36. А пакету требуется минимум 5.7

Есть два варианта решения:

1) Поднимите версию Laravel до 5.7.*

2) Установите более низкую версию  spatie/laravel-image-optimizer. Под вашу версию Laravel подойдет 1.1.2 . Но не факт что она подойдет под ваши нужды.

```
composer-php7.3 require spatie/laravel-image-optimizer:1.1.2
```

А возможно даже 1.3.1. Не совсем понятно по: 
https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/laravel-image-optimizer

Comment: у меня laravel 5.7

Comment: а как обновить с 5.4 до 5.7?